# Not understanding how set iteration is working, expecting true but returning false

Tags: python, set

I am running below function but why is it returning False, 7-3 is 4 and 4 is present in the set so it should return true.

```
from typing import List
def find_sum_of_two(A, val):
  B = set(A)
  print("B is : " + str(B))
  for i in B:
      
      if (val - i) in B:
          return True
      else:
          return False

print(find_sum_of_two([2, 1, 4, 7, 3],7))
```

Comment: You never get to the second number, because you always return during the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return False at the end of loop if your condition doesn't match:

```
def find_sum_of_two(A, val):
  B = set(A)
  print("B is : " + str(B))
  for i in B:
      if (val - i) in B:
          return True
  return False

print(find_sum_of_two([2, 1, 4, 7, 3],7))
```

Answer (score 4):

`return` only `returns` once, after the first `return` the code does not return anymore.

So try indenting out the `else` like this:

```
from typing import List
def find_sum_of_two(A, val):
    lst = []
    B = set(A)
    print("B is : " + str(B))
    for i in B:          
        if (val - i) in B:
            return True
    else:
         return False

print(find_sum_of_two([2, 1, 4, 7, 3],7))
```

Actually even now the `else` isn't required:

```
    for i in B:          
        if (val - i) in B:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks!

Comment: @SUMANBHATTACHARJEE Please accept and upvote if it works :)

Answer (score 1):

`return` marks the end of the function. Once the return statement is encountered, python considers that the function has ended. So all statements after `return` statements are unreachable.

In this, when the `return True` is executed, the function has ended. So `else` and the other `return` statement is not executed.

So taking advantage of the fact that any statement after `return` is not executed, you can remove the `else` part

```
for i in B:
    if (val - i) in B:
        return True
return False
```